# Use dollar sign as well as the math mode in lstlisting

Tags: symbols, listings

Is it ever possible? I want display the dollar sign correctly in the beginning in the bracket, then I want to display a right arrow and display another bracket.

```
\begin{lstlisting}
//basic instruction
["\$p.red"] $\rightarrow$ ["!jQuery", ".red"]

\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Not really, but look in the manual, you can set a set of char between which listings jumps back to normal latex formatting. AFAIR it is called escapeinside

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're willing to play around a bit, yes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  mathescape = true,
  basicstyle = \ttfamily}
\newcommand{\dollar}{\mbox{\textdollar}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
//basic instruction
["$\dollar$p.red"] $\rightarrow$ ["!jQuery", ".red"]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

We escape inside math mode and insert `\dollar`, which is a text version of `$`.

Comment: Ohhh so clever! <3